# using the OData Queryable with a repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, iqueryable

I have this repository method:

```
public IQueryable<TModel> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return context.Set<TModel>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

where `TModel` is an artist-model.. anyway

And then I have this action in my controller:

```
// GET api/artist
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<ArtistModel> Get()
{
    return _repo.GetAll().AsQueryable();
}
```

Now.. if I would change the repository method to return a List and also add `.ToList` for my result.. then this would work great. But then no  matter what OData query comes in.. I would still first execute a "get all query".. turn them into a list and then I would execute my OData query against that list..

Which seems just plain wrong.. what I would like to do is to make sure that the OData query gets executed the same time as I'm trying to fetch data from the database.. so I only get the very specific result matching the query.. and not a huge bunch of data that then later on gets queried..

For now I have the problem with the `DbContext` getting disposed once outside the using.. but I still need to close the `DbContext` as well some where, some how..

Any ideas?

Comment: Part of the issue in your thinking is calling the method GetAll(), because is doesn't actually do any getting. It returns a queryable object whose POTENTIAL SET of objects is all of them. If you all of a sudden add a ToList() in GetAll(), then you're changing the contact of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the queryable extension of web api is kind of confusing, since it is so different from previous versions. In the new version you need to either explicitly enable queryable  support or use the new query options class. [See this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)

Edit:Some code this since I am now at a desk

```
public IQueryable<TModel> GetAll(ODataQueryOptions opts)
    {
        var db = _repo.GetAll();
        return (IQueryable<TModel>) opts.ApplyTo(db);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but that doesnt quite cover my problem Im affraid..
The thing is that I dont want to have to do the .ToList in my repo.. since that would make a call to the database.. fetch all the rows in it.. and then later in my controller the OData-query would then query/filter the result of the list..
I would like to skip the .ToList and execute the OData-Query against the database from the begining..so I dont need to fetch a hughe record of rows from the database that might not even "fit" the query..

Comment: I am aware that you DON'T want to get the whole database out. I honestly don't think you have read all the way through the info I sent you.

Comment: I read it again :).. sorry for that.. but the thing I dont get is where and how is this disposing and disconnecting my dbcontext object?.. since I dont want to leave that connection just layin around and reserving a connection in the pool.. is the dispose and disconnection done in the ApplyTo? So to use this approach I would need to rewrite my repo to something like:

public IQueryable<TModel> GetAll()
    {
            var context = new DatabaseContext();
        
            return context.Set<TModel>().AsQueryable();
        
    }


??

Comment: Its actually fine to have DatabaseContexts not disposed. They only take connections from the connection pool when they actually need to connect to the database. You might find memory usage a little high though.

Comment: Create the DbContext in your controller ctor and dispose it in the controller's Dispose() method.

Comment: Is there a way, where i don't use Efcore, but want to add these filters before querying to database . Once my filter query is ready then want to hit to Db & fetch the info in .Net 6.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable web API queryable through a couple of ways,

1. Put the `[Queryable]` attribute on your action. Your action can return one of these - `IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>`, `HttpResponseMessage` with the content being an `ObjectContent<IQueryable<T>>` or `ObjectContent<IEnumerable<T>>`, `Task<IQueryable<T>>`, `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`with the same restrictions as earlier.
2. Enable querying globally by doing `configuration.EnableQuerySupport()`. This would enable querying for all methods that return an `IQueryable<T>`.
3. Use `ODataQueryOptions<T>` as mentioned [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) and manually applying the query yourself.

And regarding the `DbContext` disposal issue, we evaluate the query very late in a lazy fashion - when the formatter is writing the response to the stream. So, you should not dispose the `DbContext` in your action. Instead, dispose it along with the controller i.e override the controller's `Dispose` method and dispose it there. Web API takes care of the controllers life time and disposes the controller when the request is done processing. Also, you can use `Request.RegisterForDispose` method too, to dispose any resources when the request is done processing.